# Some functions in package appear as undefined Golang

Tags: go

I am attempting to create a Golang application. I have one function in my package which I can use fine, the `GetCoin` function. However, my function `CreateWallet` keeps giving me an error saying it's not defined in the package. The function name is in capitals so it's exported, but it's like my other file can't see it from the import.

Here is the package I am importing:

https://github.com/pocockn/crypto-compare-go/blob/master/handlers/handlers.go

Here is my main file.

```
import (
"github.com/pocockn/crypto-compare-go/handlers"

"github.com/labstack/echo"

)

func main() {

e := echo.New()
e.Use(middleware.Logger())
e.Use(middleware.Recover())
    e.POST("/createWallet", handlers.CreateWallet)
}
```

Comment: You didn't import the `echo` package.

Comment: I got rid of everything that wasn't relevant

Comment: CreateWallet is not declared in package handlers. It is, so I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the export of the handlers package or CreateWallet.
**middleware** is not defined, but if you comment out those two lines everything runs fine.

```
package main

import (
"github.com/pocockn/crypto-compare-go/handlers"

"github.com/labstack/echo"

)

func main() {

e := echo.New()
// e.Use(middleware.Logger())
// e.Use(middleware.Recover())
    e.POST("/createWallet", handlers.CreateWallet)
}
```